# Why is this SQL query returning duplicate results when adding conditions?

Tags: sql, duplicates

The code below is used to get counts for help desk tasks and I am attempting to retrieve counts for a specific department. However, it appears to not be working correctly, and I am at a loss for why this would be. The SQL query is below:

```
SELECT 
    datepart(mm, m.creationdate) AS themonth, 
    datepart(yyyy, m.creationdate) AS theyear, 
    count(*) AS total, count(nullif(m.thetype, '1')) AS regular, 
    count(nullif(m.thetype, '2')) AS multi, 
    count(nullif(m.thetype, 11)) AS quick, 
    count(nullif(m.enteredby, 'WriteLog')) AS mn, 
    Count(case when m.thetype=10 then 1 else null end) as Errors, 
    Count(case when m.thetype=12 then 1 else null end) as FOH 
FROM mlist AS m 
INNER JOIN TypeList AS t ON t.typekey = m.thetype 
INNER JOIN Notes AS mn ON m.id = mn.id 
WHERE mn.enteredby in ('210','181','229','240','266','284','291','238','239','272','273') 
GROUP BY datepart(mm, m.creationdate), datepart(yyyy, m.creationdate) 
ORDER BY datepart(yyyy, m.creationdate) DESC, datepart(mm, m.creationdate) DESC
```

I recently added the portion:

```
WHERE mn.enteredby in ('210','181','229','240','266','284','291','238','239','272','273')
```

Which resulted in higher counts in many cases, which doesn't make any sense unless they are duplicate results. Is there an obvious issue here?

Comment: You may want to create a sqlfiddle to demonstrate your problem.  As is, it's difficult to guess what might be happening.  However, if you omit the `where` criteria, I would find it hard to believe your numbers would be lower than with it.  The `where` criteria should be restricting the overall set -- without it, you have all, with it you should have all to none...